# Trying to mimic hierarchy by sorting array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array the following way in PHP:

```
array
0 =>    id:1203
        parent_id: 456

1 =>    id:456
        parent_id:1723

2 =>    id:1723
        parent_id:0
```

to this:

```
array   
0 =>    id:1723
        parent_id:0

1 =>    id:456
        parent_id:1723

2 =>    id:1203
        parent_id:456
```

I never sorted an array in PHP before. How would you do it?

Thanks

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you are trying to sort it so that the parent_id is the preceding id? How are you determining what should be the initial ID to start cascading from?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. But yeah the initial id would be the one that doesn't have a parent id. Picture it as a tree. If an array doesn't have a parent_id then it's the root basically.

Answer (score 1):

Is this doing what you want ?

```
$arr = array(
    array('id' => 1203, 'parent_id' =>  456),
    array('id' =>  456, 'parent_id' => 1723),
    array('id' => 1723, 'parent_id' =>    0)
);

function compare($a, $b) {

    if ($a['parent_id'] == 0) return -1;
    if ($b['parent_id'] == 0) return 1;

    if ($a['id'] == $b['parent_id']) return -1;
    if ($b['id'] == $a['parent_id']) return 1;

    return 0;
}

usort($arr, 'compare');

print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1723
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 456
            [parent_id] => 1723
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1203
            [parent_id] => 456
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see whats the criteria you want to use to sort. Anyway, you could use [uasort function](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.uasort.php) , in which you pass a custom function as argument, so in that function you can define whatever criteria you want to order your array. That function would receive 2 arguments (the 2 variables to compare), and you could compare both parent_id (or whatever is you want to compare). To learn what your custom function should return, check [this out](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

By using uasort instead of usort you can keep your array indexes (as you said in your example).